# Swift Extension Issues

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swift iOS application that uses different secp256k1 pods as well as Array, Data and other extensions.

If I build the module on its own and test everything works.

The moment I bring the module/pod into my project the tests fail.

Is there a good way to find out if the module/pod is calling the wrong Data extension? How can I tell? Is there a hierarchy I can look at?

I don't really have code as I'm not sure where the issue is and the project is very big.

So for an example, if I had a Data extension in my project, and a Data extension in a pod, which Data extension is used and how can I verify?

Thank You

EDIT:

It seems to be an issue with secp256k1, UnsafeMutablePointer and my getPointer() function.

In the module/pod its retiring a different pointer than in the application.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step into the code?

Comment: You should change the name of your extension method. Or edit secp256k1 to make its extension internal.